# mysql stored procedure multiple parameters

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to add multiple dynamic columns in the select statement, (stored procedure) But it's not working at my end, Can you please help me on same.

```
BEGIN SET @col1 = col1;SET @col1 = col2;SET @getID = CONCAT('SELECT ' ,@col1 = col1, @col2 = col2,' FROM',tablename_In,' WHERE `type`= type ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ?,?'); PREPARE stmt FROM @getID;SET @START =_START; SET @LIMIT = _LIMIT;EXECUTE stmt USING @START, @LIMIT; DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt; END
```

Also, I have another stored procedure it's also not working with between query:

```
BEGIN SET @getID = CONCAT('SELECT count(id) as co FROM ',tablename_In,' WHERE',est_time,' BETWEEN',start_date,'AND',end_date);PREPARE stmt FROM @getID;  EXECUTE stmt; DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt; END
```

Comment: There are missing spaces in @GetId in both lines. In line 1 after FROM, in line 2 after WHERE, BETWEEN, AND.

Comment: I have removed the space but it's still not working at my end .

Comment: What error do you get, or what is the result of running the queries?

Comment: I am not getting any kind of error message , But if I add simple procedure then it's working fine , I want pass everything dynamically , column name table name also where conditions .

Simple store procedure are working fine .
BEGIN
 SELECT count(id) as co
 FROM mytablename
 WHERE est_time BETWEEN start_date AND end_date AND type = type;
 END

Comment: You said "I have removed the space", but what I meant was that you should *add* spaces.

Comment: Thanks @grahamj42 , I have tried both , But still not working .